# Template and model in TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker, templates

How can I create a template using TeXmaker?
I would create a default file and use it every time I need to make a new LaTeX file.

For example using MS Word it's possible save a document as model and use it every time I need it. Is it possible also in TeXmaker?

Comment: TeXMaker knows the File menu option `New by copying existing file` and the `Wizard` menu option(s). But I wouldn't say those are 'templates'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Open an empty new file;
2. Write there the code for your template file;
3. Save it to a convenient location that you can remember;
4. To open the template, do **`File > New by copying an existing file`**

This will give you a copy of your document without a file name, and you must do a **`Save As`** before compiling.

**Caution**: A very strong negative against templates is that you often just perpetuate the problems and poor structure of the past.   So you must become diligent in keeping the template properly updated.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **`User > User Tags > Edit User Tags`** like in the following picture:

[image]

Choose a *menu item*, and give it the name in **`Menu Item`** (on the right), with which you want to identify this template.

[image]

In **`LaTeX Content`**, write the code for your template; the code could be something like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\author{@}
\title{@}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents % for a table of contents

\section{@} 

\end{document}
```

`@` is for TexMaker dot.

To use your template, open new file go to **`User > User Tags`**, and choose the user tag you want.

Comment: This solution is not bad, but I think it has a "bug" because when I go to user->user tags-> "name of tags" it past a different text that I had copied.
So I prefer the solution of R. Schumacher, but I thank you all!

Comment: I'm not sure what "TeXMaker dot" is, just by reading this (the `@`).