# Is there an editor that allows you to make custom file templates?

Tags: templates, editors

If I open new files often in which I would like to have some code pre-written, is there a way to save a template with this format in a Latex editor to always have that file format on hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many of them. For example:

- [TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284425/loading-a-custom-template-in-texstudio)
- [Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231744/template-and-model-in-texmaker)
- For [Kile](https://docs.kde.org/trunk4/en/extragear-office/kile/kile.pdf) see page 21

Almost all LaTeX editors have an option to create a custom template, so it will be better to choose one and then search, this site for example, how to do what you want.